# EF Core Includes query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I am attempting to save a User entity to a Room entity in EFCore w/ SQLite. Right after I save the changes I query the database again to get the updated list of users in the room entity. Currently, it returns 0 users, if I stop the code with a break point after it runs this query and look in the database table, I can see the users are associated with the right Room, however I still have 0 results. I am curious if my design or lack there of is the problem? Do I need something that links the user back to the room?

Code that returns 0 users -

```
public async Task<ServiceResponse<MatchRoom>> RegisterUser(AppState state)
{
    //Update the db with connection ID incase we need it later
    var update = _context.Update(state.user);
    if (update != null)
    {
        //The user object is saved here
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        //Here I query a room, that the user is assigned to, but get nothing.
        var room = _context.MatchRooms.Include("Users");
}
```

I have the following dbcontext

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        //
    }
    
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MatchRoom> MatchRooms { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Message> Messages { get; set; }
    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MatchRoom>()
            .HasMany<User>(u => u.Users);
            
        modelBuilder.Entity<MatchRoom>()
            .HasMany<Message>(m => m.Messages);
            
        modelBuilder.Entity<Message>()
            .HasOne<User>(r => r.SentBy);
    }    
}

public class MatchRoom
{
    public int MatchRoomId { get; set; }
    public string MatchRoomCode { get; set; }
    [ValidateComplexType]
    public List<User> Users { get; set; } = new List<User>();
    public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public List<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserCode { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="You must specify a username")]
    [StringLength(20,MinimumLength=1,ErrorMessage="Please enter a username no longer than 20 characters")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionId { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public int MessageId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public User SentBy { get; set; }
}
```

[image: Code]
[image: db]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only declaring the query, but not executing it.

Change the following line -

```
var room = _context.MatchRooms.Include("Users");
```

to -

```
var room = await _context.MatchRooms.Include(p=> p.Users).ToListAsync();
```

This will give you a list of all `MatchRoom` along with their related `User` lists.

Not sure how you can query a room, that the saved user is assigned to, because I don't see any foreign key property in `User` class like `MatchRoomId` that you can use to filter the query. Right now they are being handled by EF generated shadow key, I guess.

Declare a foreign key property in `User` class -

```
public int MatchRoomId { get; set; }
```

Then you can query a single room, that the saved user is assigned to like -

```
var room = await _context.MatchRooms.Include(p=> p.Users).FirstOrDefaultAsync(p=> p.MatchRoomId == state.user.MatchRoomId)
```

Comment: How do I assign the MatchRoomId to the user class? Just add a property?

Comment: I think you didn't configure foreign key for `User` table. Could you share your entity configuration code?

Comment: All I have is the DBContext as posted above - would I add it there? Or do you mean the DataContextModelSnapshot.cs?

Comment: @Parakoopa Add `public int MatchRoomId { get; set; }` this property in the `User` class. Then create new migration and new database.

Comment: thank you, that was it. Seems I have some studying to do.